# Is it possible to specify multiple upstream ssh proxys for openssh in linux

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

Is it possible to configure openssh to use a specific upstream ssh server when connecting to a specific IP range in order to have a single ssh server that client connect through to get to multiple IP segments on a network?

An example being they configure an ssh client to connect to 10.1.1.10 via 10.1.1.2 but when connecting to 10.2.2.10 they go via 10.1.1.2 and then that forwards it on to 10.2.2.2 to get the the end host of 10.2.2.10. Using multiple OpenSSH servers in Linux.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

SSH has the ProxyCommand directive, which will get you partway there. For the rest, you'll need to string together a series of port forwards to get all the way from the source tonthebdestination.